# Symfony2 FOSUserbundle disallow anonymous access

Tags: symfony

My entire webpage has to be private with only authenticated users accepted. I'm using FOSUserBundle and have this as setting:

security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

When I set anonymous as false or get rid of it, I get a "problem loading page" error where the page will just crash. Also, when anonymous is true, when I login with the right credentials it logs me in but does not redirect to the main index page, instead it stays on /login and gives me "Logged in as user | Logout".

So the behavior I need it to be is:

1) On homepage, it will redirect to /login page if user is not authenticated (no anonymous users)
2) After login authenticated, redirects to homepage

Answer (score 1):

It is all done in firewall settings

1) add firewall rule:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
```

2) add `default_target_path`:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /
```

Comment: For reference: Here are links to all the configurable properties for fosuserbundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md

and for symfony's security component:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html